# scroll with scrollIntoView not working in chrome when call in HostListener event

Tags: angular, typescript

i write a function for scroll page and when i call this function in HTML (click), it is work (it is true in fire fox and chrome)

but when i call this function in type script code it is work in fire fox and do not work chrome

```
 @ViewChild('scrollCourse', { static: false })
 scrollCourse: ElementRef;
```

this is my scroll function

```
  async scrollToCourse() {
    this.desableFirstScroll=true
    await this.scrollCourse.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    this.desableFirstScroll=false
  }
```

and this is HTML element

```
<div #scrollCourse class="container-fluid multi-carousel kargah">
```

when i click this button all of them is true

```
 <button class="btn" type="button" color="success"
  rounded="true" (click)="scrollToCourse()"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher icon"></i></button>
```

but i want call this function when page is scrolling

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
@HostListener("window:load", ['$event'])
getScreenSize(event?) {
 this.scrHeight = window.innerHeight;
 const number = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.scrollY || 0;
 // set fix kargah nav
 if (number > this.scrHeight && number < this.scrHeight + 150 && this.kargahScrollFirst) {
  if(this.desableFirstScroll == false){

    this.scrollToCourse();
    this.kargahScrollFirst = false;
  }
 }
 if ((number > (this.scrHeight + 150) || number < this.scrHeight) && !this.kargahScrollFirst) {
    this.kargahScrollFirst = true;
 }
```

i tested call function proccess with log and function calling is true

```
async scrollToCourse() {
 this.desableFirstScroll=true
 await this.scrollKargah.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behaviour: "smooth" });
 console.log("chorm",this.scrollCourse.nativeElement);
 this.desableFirstScroll=false
}
```

this log return element information

my log when call function in scrolling event:

```
chorm <div _ngcontent-asg-c5 class=​"container-fluid multi-carousel kargah">​<div _ngcontent-asg-c5 class=​" row multi-slide-box">​…​</div>​</div>​
```

Comment: Can  you share it in stackbiltz?

Comment: I used many library so share in stackbiltz is difficult